# Disable hand written text detection

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am using **`Google.Cloud.Vision.V1`** for OCR.
I need to disable the hand written text detection in method when I call the "`DetectDocumentText`" method in "`ImageAnnotatorClient`" class.
I only want to perform the OCR not ICR.

This is the code snippet I am using:

```
FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(imageFile);
var image = Image.FromFile(fi.FullName);
var client = ImageAnnotatorClient.Create();
var response = client.DetectDocumentText(image);
```

Comment: can you specify what in ICR you are looking forward to detect? Are you looking for the font or to train a model to recognize a specific handwriting?

Comment: I just want to do OCR. No ICR should be performed on the document. The results should only comprise of OCR results.